# How add \n to enter key press

Tags: javascript

I need add '\n' to my text area tag when user press Enter key. Because default enter add only visual new string, if i copy text from text area in other place i have one string.
If i try

```
 $('.body__textarea').on('keydown', function (e) {
   if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
     e.preventDefault();
     const oldValue = $(this).val();
     const newValue = oldValue + '\n'
     $(this).val(newValue);
   }  
 })
```

New line adds in the end of string, but need where is caret.

Code example https://codepen.io/kostikovmu/pen/oNXqmoM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me was change "copy" event:

```
const source = document.querySelector('.body__textarea');

source.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  const selection = document.getSelection();
  event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', selection.toString());
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use`<br>` 
 instead of `\n`

Comment: const newValue = oldValue + '<br>'. You can have a try

Comment: Your solution not work. I add code example link in question.